# Delphi: intercept file writes, receive them in my app

Tags: delphi

Is there any way, with Delphi (10.3) to "hook" into a specific file, and intercept all the writes performed by another app? so everytime any app wants to write to that file, my app will receive the data instead and the file won't be modified in the disk.

Comment: No, you'ld have to do it for every file I/O operation system-wide, and it would trigger every halfway competent antivirus software anyway.

Comment: What if I create the file in my app? or somehow create a filemapping to a virtual file that my app can read, like you would do for a ntfs symbolic link

Comment: How would that *intercept all the writes performed by another app* or handle *everytime every app wants to write to that file, my app will receive the data instead*? The apps are going to request a file handle from the OS that they receive from opening the file, and the OS isn't going to ask your app to provide that handle unless you write a filesystem driver (which a) you can't write in Delphi, and b) would be system-wide for all filesystem writes).

Comment: Inject code into the other app. And disable the anti malware.

Comment: @KenWhite Why do you think you can't write a file system driver in Delphi?

Comment: @SilverWarior: You can write a file system driver in Delphi, but not one low-level enough to replace the OS driver entirely, AFAIK. I could be wrong (it wouldn't be the first time), but it would still be a major undertaking and overkill for whatever XY problem this poster is trying to solve.

Comment: A file system filter driver would do this [What Is a File System Filter Driver?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/what-is-a-file-system-filter-driver-). There are pre-built solutions available (just search on file system filter driver Delphi).

Comment: @SilverWarior Presumably because it would be a kernel mode driver, and therefore not something that could be compiled by Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you only need to extend current Windows File System with something like Vrtual File Structure then you can achieve this with a User Mode Driver which can be made with Delphi. But of you would want to replace the existing Windows File System then you would indeed need to use kernel mode driver which can't ba made with Delphi.